# Virustotal API - Get list of All Subdomains

Tags: python, json, subdomain

I'm looking to get the list of all subdomains of a URL, uisng the [Virustotal API](https://developers.virustotal.com/reference/overview)

Running Google.com as an example through their website, I can see that Virustotal registers a total of 3.2k subdomains for Google.com
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/domain/google.com/relations -> subdomains [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgM47.png)

Using the API, however, I get a list of only 100 subdomains.

```
import vt
import requests

url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/domain/report'

params = {'apikey':'MY_API_KEY','domain':'google.com'}

response = requests.get(url, params=params)

print(response.json())
```

Is there an option to get ALL the subdomains in the response?

I tried the V2 and V3 API, crosschecked with their online GUI to confirm that my code wasn't return all available output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the Virus Total api, there is a parameter called `limit` that is default set at 100.

I am assuming if you want to change it you would have to add it to your parameters entry.

```
import vt
import requests

url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/domain/report'

params = {'apikey':'MY_API_KEY','domain':'google.com','limit': 100}

response = requests.get(url, params=params)

print(response.json())
```